# Task factory force more tasks to start at the beginning

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, massive, taskfactory

i am filling a task factory with tasks something like this (pseudocode):

```
private int _taskcounter;
```

snip

```
var factory = new TaskFactory();
for(var i = 0;i<1000;i++)
   factory.StartNew(() => doWork());
```

snip

```
private void doWork(){
   Interlocked.Increment(ref _taskcounter);
   //do some slow I/O work here
   Interlocked.Decrement(ref _taskcounter);
}
```

if you now watch the _taskcounter you can see 
initially its starting about 10 tasks
but then it starts 1 to 2 tasks/s until the queue is finished.

petty obvious behavior, isnt it?

my question is:
is there a way to force the task factory to start more tasks on the start?

im already limiting the maximum of running tasks with a variation of some msdn example class to prevent excessive memory consumption.
 or is there something wrong with this funny measurement method or my consideration?

its not necessary to run all the work in different threads otherwise i wouldnt use the factory

 i only want benefit from the non work stealing behavior of the factory.

for everything else im relying on the intelligence of the factory.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to start so many tasks at once? What are they doing? Are sure doing in many times in parallel will speed up the process?

Comment: it definitely will. As ive already said these are slow tcp io tasks. io tasks are 99% waiting for the hardware/network resource to respond so there is an big impact due the speed while parallelizing the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know TaskFactory uses ThreadPool, so you can try [SetMaxThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. But actually it is designed to optimize resources consumption. So I don't think you will get much efficency increase.

Also you can try to start thread manually with `new Thread()`, this should help you to start many threads immidately, but agian I don't think you will get much efficency increase.

Comment: The taskfactory is doing exactly what it should but if you run massive queues it needs more then 10 minutes to reach maximum efficiency. i only want to speedup this process.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't. It reaches maximum only after 10 minutes because of its optimization mechanism. It doesn't know what to wait from a programmer many short tasks or one long or many long tasks (as in your case). Try to use `SetMinThreads`, if you know the value. MSDN says TP will create this count of thread immideately.

Comment: ill try this. sounds good. btw the theadpool never reaches a max. it would produce tasks/threads untill the memory overflows. its not as smart as you would expect

Comment: ive tried it. you couldnt use this parameter with the taskfactory directly but ive overrided parts of the methods and implemented the SetMinThreads. it works like charm. I think meanwhile im using it more like a normal threadpool than a taskfactory xD